# Passing multiple values to ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to pass multiple values to a controller. The controller looks like

```
Page(string type, string keywords, string sortType)
```

In a asp.net page,

I have

```
<%=Url.Action("Page", "Search", new { type = "new",keywords = keywords, sortType = "Date" }) %>
```

But the values for type and sorType are passed as null inside the controller.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What URL does the Url.Action generate? Also check your routes.

Comment: Routes are fine, I only have one route it does enter there. Keywords are passing fine as string, but type and sortType both are null.

Comment: Ok, when you view the page with that link, what does the generated link actually look like, e.g. `http://blah/Search/Page/?type=new&keywords=blahblah&sortType=Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just double-checked, and this should work fine. I created this controller method in a new MVC app's Home controller:

```
public ActionResult Page(string type, string keywords, string sortType)
{
    this.ViewData["Type"] = type;
    this.ViewData["Keywords"] = keywords;
    this.ViewData["SortType"] = sortType;
    return this.View("Index");
}
```

and then added this to the Index view:

```
<ul>
<% foreach (var item in ViewData) { %>
    <li><%: item.Key %> = <%: string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value as string) ? "null" : item.Value %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>

<%: Html.ActionLink("Hello", "Page", "Home", new { type = "new", keywords = "blahblah", sortType = "Date" }, null) %>
```

The page correctly displays the following after clicking the "Hello" link:

```
o Type = new
o Keywords = blahblah
o SortType = Date
```

So if this works in a simple new MVC app, I think it must be either other methods in your controller or a routing problem causing it.

Comment: The solution was to create a string and then consume it<% string sType = "Date";%>

<%=Url.Action("Page", "Search", new { type = "new",keywords = keywords, sortType = sType }) %>

Otherwise i would keep getting null. and that is ridiculous!!!